# negative number in fibonacci

Tags: go, fibonacci

If I check my code for number like **6** in the output I have got **8** which is correct. If I have **99** then I have got negative number. What is wrong with this code:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

var num = 94

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("%d\n", fibo(num))
}

func fibo(num int) int{
  a, b := 0, 1
  for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    a, b = b, a + b
  }
  return a
}
```

Comment: It's possibly an overflow issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the return type of your `fibo` function from `int` to `uint64` and also declare `a` and `b` as `uint64`, as with an `int` output it's going to overflow and that's why you get a negative value as a result:

```
func fibo(num int) uint64{
  var a, b uint64 = 0, 1
  for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    a, b = b, a + b
  }
  return a
}
```

However it's still far from the perfect solution as for elements with higher indices than 93 overflow will happen.

**UPDATE: To work for arbitrary large numbers.**

So with Go's `big` package you can get a working `fibo` function (at least it seems like).

Try out this one as well:

```
package main


import (
"fmt"
"math/big"
)


var num int = 94

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("%d\n", fibo(num))
}

func fibo(num int) *big.Int{
  var a, b, t *big.Int = big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(0)

  for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    t.Set(a)

    a.Set(b)
    b.Add(b, t)

  }
  return a
}
```

For `fibo(94)`it will output:

```
19740274219868223167
```

Which seems legit as in `Python` I get the same result with the same logic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Additional fun fact on the overflow. The maximum value for an `int` value is roughly 2 bn. The value of `fibo(99)` is something like 218.922.995.834 bn (nope, not a typo). Just so you get an idea of the scale of the overflow :-)

Comment: Exactly, it's still not working for numbers as big like `fibo(99)` neither for `fibo(94)` as it's included in the example. At the moment I'm taking a look at package `big` that may can provide an arbitrary datatype for this issue.